# Preventing AdMob Invalid activity

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, admob, adsense

I have been getting some amounts between $0.2 to $0.7 debited from my final payment from AdMob ads under the title "**invalid activity**" in my payment details.

Yes the amounts are small but i am still worried as i have been extra careful while testing i used the test keys and i have not told any of my friends to click on my ads or have clicked on them myself.

I did have the same issue for my web-site but that was due to some bots which i black-listed in the server access files so i am no longer getting such "invalid activity" on my blog earnings

I have built my apps in Ionic Framework.

So my question is how can i **detect** where the invalid activity is coming from in my app and how can i **prevent** it.

Answer (score 1):

> How can i detect where the invalid activity is coming from in my app

You can check a country wise view of requests on Google Adsense at [this link](https://www.google.com/adsense/app?hl=en_US&gsessionid=v0hmg-GEG8uP0CyfqXcEdg#main/viewreports/d=today&ag=country&dd=&ss=&oo=ascending&gm=earnings&co=d&drh=false&ct=g&oet=&ert=&se=&uim=d&tz=a&rt=n). You can analyze and check where major traffic is from, where clicks are from, etc.

Fore more detailed reporting use [Google Analytics for Android](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/)

> How can i prevent it.

There is no fixed way of how you deal with that. You will need to take steps and write algorithms in your app based on your analysis. But, I dont think that is really required. If it is an invalid activity from a third party (NOT You) Google will take corrective actions. But, if it is by You, you are in trouble and may get the app suspended or account blocked.

Answer (score 0):

google doesn't provide actual invalid activity because of security reason according to google terms& conditions